# Downloading and executing script

Tags: linux, bash, script

I'm sorry for asking this but I couldn't find anything of help. I'm asked to download the script "install_esoreflex" (ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/reflex/install_esoreflex) and then execute the following commands:

```
chmod u+x install_esoreflex

./install_esoreflex
```

But I'm not sure if "download the script" means download as a text file or copy and paste the script on a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `chmod u+x install_esoreflex` `install_esoreflex` is a file in your current working directory. The same with `./install_esoreflex`. You need this file to exist, so "downloading as a text file" is definitely the right interpretation. E.g. you can download the file with `wget`:

```
wget ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/reflex/install_esoreflex
```

then proceed as you were told.

Technically copying and pasting *may* work as well (without `chmod` and `./install_esoreflex` at all). This method has its downsides though. Since you were guided to download, you shouldn't just copy and paste.

Note: executing a script (regardless whether with downloading or pasting) from untrusted source is unsafe in general. Run `./install_esoreflex` only if you trust the source.

Comment: Thanks. So I should put all that's in the link on a text file and name it install_esoreflex?

Comment: @bajotupie Yes, it should work. Or just use `wget` (see the edited answer).

Comment: The program only works with Python2, I have Python 3 and 2 but the script doesn't know since it warns me. Maybe you can help me to solve this. Happy holidays!

Comment: @bajotupie Well… I cannot, not my expertise. But even if I could, I shouldn't help you *here*. One issue, one question. I think I have answered the original question. If any additional issue appeared then please ask a new question (after doing your own research etc., so the new question is decent quality).

Answer (score 0):

This command downloads the file and executes it at the same time:

```
wget ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/reflex/install_esoreflex  -O - | sh
```

If you want the script to find the correct python version try this:

```
wget ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/reflex/install_esoreflex  -O - | sed 's/command -v python/command -v python2/g' | sh
```

Comment: Please note the second part of your answer addresses the side issue from one of the comments. Problems with Python are not in the scope of the question. However there is [another question](https://superuser.com/q/1387649/432690) from the same user. I believe the second part of your answer belongs there.