# Change Python version a script is referring to

Tags: bash, script, python, ubuntu-18.04, python3

I have downloaded the script "install_esoreflex" (ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/reflex/install_esoreflex) and then execute the following commands:

```
chmod u+x install_esoreflex

./install_esoreflex
```

I get the following warnings

```
WARNING: The following Python version is installed in your system Python 3.7.0
WARNING: Some of the available workflows use functionality
WARNING: only available in version Python 2.6.0 or greater
WARNING: and will not work properly with the installed version.
WARNING: Additionally, python 3.x is not yet supported.
```

Eventhough I have both Python 3.7.0 and 2.7. Python 2 is installed in     /usr/bin/python2 and Python 3 is installed in /home/USER/miniconda3/bin/python3.
How can I make the script "know" I have python 2?

Comment: Does the command `python —version` give you Python 2 or 3? If it gives version 3, type `alias python=python2` and then run the script. This points `python` to version 2 instead of 3.

Comment: You must have `python3` first in `$PATH`. Try: `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH ./install_esoreflex`.

Comment: @agtoever it gives Python 3. You mean I have to run `alias python=python2` and then `./install_esoreflex` in the same terminal?

Comment: Added it as an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Ubuntu version 18.04, python 3 is the default python version ([link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-python-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)). This means that `/usr/bin/python` is symlinked to `/usr/bin/python3`. You can check this by running `python —version`.

To default to python 2 in scripts (as your install script requires), you need to install the python 2 version (`apt-get install python2`). And tell Ubuntu to use that python version.

It is **not** recommended to change the `/usr/bin/python` symlink, because it is part of the distribution maintained configuration. Instead you should use the `alias` command ([link](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/aliash.html)): `alias python=python2`. This (locally) points `python` to `python2`, which is found in `/usr/bin`. You could use this command once in the terminal before running your install script. To change it more permanently, add it to your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

See if the script has a "shebang" (first line with `#!...`) and change the `python` reference in it to point to `python2` instead of just `python`

Edit:

OK, so the whole script assumes that your default `python` is Python v2. You can perhaps get an installation run successfully using an alias (`alias python=python2`) as indicated in comments above.

However, it is likely that the whole package expects `python` to be python v2, so you will have to do the same each time you run something from the package. But if you set a permanent alias this may conflict with other things in your system that expect python=python3.

So you may have to use facade scripts to launch parts of that package after setting up an alias for python v2.

Comment: The first line is `#!/bin/sh`. How do I change the python reference?

Comment: Edited the answer...

Comment: the script looks the python binary using command-v python, change that line to command -v python2

Answer (score 0):

this solves your problem in one line without changing system's python symlink which can lead to other problems.

```
wget ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/reflex/install_esoreflex  -O - | sed 's/command -v python/command -v python2/g' | sh
```